# "java.lang.ClassCastException" is returned when creating events

Tags: java, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an event using Microsoft Graph.
Sometimes I get a ClassCastException, but I don't know why
What is the case "response binary" is returned when creating events?

My code is like this:

```
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new GraphAuthProvider(accessToken);
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();

Event event = graphClient
                .users(USER)
                .events()
                .buildRequest(requestOptions)
                .post(event);
```

I got this error:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Event"
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Event
        at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.EventRequest.post(EventRequest.java:112)
        at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.EventCollectionRequest.post(EventCollectionRequest.java:67)
```

When `graphClient.getLogger().setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.DEBUG);` is added:

```
Starting to send request, URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USER/events
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
Request Method PATCH
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
Sending com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Event as request body
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
Serializing type Event
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
Response code 200, OK
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
Response binary
com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
Deserializing type Event
```

Looking at the　log with SDK, I guess that if "Response binary" is returned, the above error will occur.
It only happens on the remote computer and I can't debug in the library.
What is the case "response binary" is returned when creating events?

This is the library I'm using.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm sorry if my English is hard to understand.
It would be helpful if you give me answer.

Comment: I tried with creating event using MS Graph explorer/POSTMAN, but i failed to repro the issue. So i wonder have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried with the Java code and I was also unable to repro the issue.

Comment: This did not happen when using microsoft-graph 2.3.0. This has happened in version 1.7.0 as described and the cause is unknown.

Comment: Glad to hear and i would recommend you the use the latest builds/SDKs only. Looks like it may be a bug or regression, which might have been fixed in later versions. That's why i always use the latest SDKs/builds and see if you can repro the issue.

Comment: Moving this to answer. consider upvoting this; so this can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the use the latest builds/SDKs only, not the older builds. Even if it may be a bug or regression, which might have been fixed in later versions. That's why i always use the latest SDKs/builds and see if you can repro the issue. Glad that you tried it and it worked for you.